# Management page won't load when using RabbitMQ docker container

Tags: docker, rabbitmq

I'm running RabbitMQ locally using:

```
docker run -it --rm --name rabbitmq -p 5672:5672 -p 15672:15672 rabbitmq:3-management
```

Some log:

```
narley@brittes ~ $ docker run -it --rm --name rabbitmq -p 5672:5672 -p 15672:15672 rabbitmq:3-management
2020-01-08 22:31:52.079 [info] <0.8.0> Feature flags: list of feature flags found:
2020-01-08 22:31:52.079 [info] <0.8.0> Feature flags:   [ ] drop_unroutable_metric
2020-01-08 22:31:52.079 [info] <0.8.0> Feature flags:   [ ] empty_basic_get_metric
2020-01-08 22:31:52.079 [info] <0.8.0> Feature flags:   [ ] implicit_default_bindings
2020-01-08 22:31:52.080 [info] <0.8.0> Feature flags:   [ ] quorum_queue
2020-01-08 22:31:52.080 [info] <0.8.0> Feature flags:   [ ] virtual_host_metadata
2020-01-08 22:31:52.080 [info] <0.8.0> Feature flags: feature flag states written to disk: yes
2020-01-08 22:31:52.160 [info] <0.268.0> ra: meta data store initialised. 0 record(s) recovered
2020-01-08 22:31:52.162 [info] <0.273.0> WAL: recovering []
2020-01-08 22:31:52.164 [info] <0.277.0> 
 Starting RabbitMQ 3.8.2 on Erlang 22.2.1
 Copyright (c) 2007-2019 Pivotal Software, Inc.
 Licensed under the MPL 1.1. Website: https://rabbitmq.com

  ##  ##      RabbitMQ 3.8.2
  ##  ##
  ##########  Copyright (c) 2007-2019 Pivotal Software, Inc.
  ######  ##
  ##########  Licensed under the MPL 1.1. Website: https://rabbitmq.com

  Doc guides: https://rabbitmq.com/documentation.html
  Support:    https://rabbitmq.com/contact.html
  Tutorials:  https://rabbitmq.com/getstarted.html
  Monitoring: https://rabbitmq.com/monitoring.html

  Logs: <stdout>

  Config file(s): /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf

  Starting broker...2020-01-08 22:31:52.166 [info] <0.277.0> 
 node           : rabbit@1586b4698736
 home dir       : /var/lib/rabbitmq
 config file(s) : /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf
 cookie hash    : bwlnCFiUchzEkgAOsZwQ1w==
 log(s)         : <stdout>
 database dir   : /var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@1586b4698736
2020-01-08 22:31:52.210 [info] <0.277.0> Running boot step pre_boot defined by app rabbit
...
...
...
2020-01-08 22:31:53.817 [info] <0.277.0> Setting up a table for connection tracking on this node: tracked_connection_on_node_rabbit@1586b4698736
2020-01-08 22:31:53.827 [info] <0.277.0> Setting up a table for per-vhost connection counting on this node: tracked_connection_per_vhost_on_node_rabbit@1586b4698736
2020-01-08 22:31:53.828 [info] <0.277.0> Running boot step routing_ready defined by app rabbit
2020-01-08 22:31:53.828 [info] <0.277.0> Running boot step pre_flight defined by app rabbit
2020-01-08 22:31:53.828 [info] <0.277.0> Running boot step notify_cluster defined by app rabbit
2020-01-08 22:31:53.829 [info] <0.277.0> Running boot step networking defined by app rabbit
2020-01-08 22:31:53.833 [info] <0.624.0> started TCP listener on [::]:5672
2020-01-08 22:31:53.833 [info] <0.277.0> Running boot step cluster_name defined by app rabbit
2020-01-08 22:31:53.833 [info] <0.277.0> Running boot step direct_client defined by app rabbit
2020-01-08 22:31:53.922 [info] <0.674.0> Management plugin: HTTP (non-TLS) listener started on port 15672
2020-01-08 22:31:53.922 [info] <0.780.0> Statistics database started.
2020-01-08 22:31:53.923 [info] <0.779.0> Starting worker pool 'management_worker_pool' with 3 processes in it
 completed with 3 plugins.
2020-01-08 22:31:54.316 [info] <0.8.0> Server startup complete; 3 plugins started.
 * rabbitmq_management
 * rabbitmq_management_agent
 * rabbitmq_web_dispatch
```

Then I go to `http:localhost:15672` and page doesn't load. No error is displayed.

Interesting thing is that it worked last time I used it (about 3 weeks ago).

Can anyone give me some help?
Cheers!

Comment: Works on my machine :)

Answer (score 1):

have a try:

step 1, going into docker container

```bash
docker exec -it rabbitmq bash
```

step 2, run it in docker container

```bash
rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management
```

is work for me

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by simply upgrading docker.
Was running docker `18.09.7` and upgrade to `19.03.5`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, clearing the cookies up has fixed this issue instantly.